# Removing lines that don't contain certain text

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I have a text file with a large amount of domains in it.  I want to remove all domains that aren't one of these extensions:

```
.com
.net
.org
.biz
.us
```

I've tried a couple ways, but nothing seems to work.  The main issue I'm running into is that certain lines aren't being removed.

For example, domains ending in `.com.br` aren't being removed because they have `.com` in the line, but I actually want them to be removed...

If this were the file:

```
test.com
example.com.br
testing.net
```

Then it should become this:

```
test.com
testing.net
```

It seems like there should be a way to do this with `sed` but I just can't make it work :/

This is what I tried doing:

```
sed '/.com$\|.net$\|.org$\|.biz$\|.us$/!d' *.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Just added the most recent way I tried: `sed '/.com$\|.net$\|.org$\|.biz$\|.us$/!d' *.txt`

Comment: I think you're doing it well, just provide the `-r` flag to `sed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, whether you can use `awk` in your environment, with actual data, for given input below one should work:

```
$ cat domain_ext_file 
.com
.net
.org
.biz
.us

$ cat site_list 
test.com
example.com.br
testing.net

$ awk -F'.' 'FNR==NR{a[$NF];next}$NF in a' domain_ext_file site_list 
test.com
testing.net
```

**Explanation:**

- set field separator as dot `(.)`, store last field (`$NF`) from domain_ext_file, in array `a`, go to next line
- while reading second file (`site_list`), if array `a` has key/index which is 2nd file's last field (`$NF in a`), then print such row/record/line

Answer (score 0):

I see you did not paste the exact input you are using, but this should work as it is really straight forward.

```
ubuntu$ cat  text.txt
.com
.net
.org
.biz
.us
.com.br
.mlp
.grrr

ubuntu$ grep -E  '[.]com$|[.]net$|[.]org$|[.]biz$|[.]us$' text.txt
.com
.net
.org
.biz
.us
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
grep  '\.\(com\|net\|org\|biz\|us\)$'
```

More readable with extended regular expressions, if supported by your version:

```
grep  -E '\.(com|net|org|biz|us)$'
```